# Elastic search query using bool instead of not

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-py

I'm trying to construct an elasticsearch query for `not` using `bool`, since `not` is deprecated. E.g. Match all documents that don't belong to `foo@bar.com`.

I tried these using elasticsearch-dsl (following this post https://www.elastic.co/blog/lost-in-translation-boolean-operations-and-filters-in-the-bool-query):

```
{'query': {
    'bool': {
        'must_not': [{
            'match': {
                'author': 'foo@bar.com'
            }
        }]
    }
}}
```

This returns no results although documents other than `'author': 'foo@bar.com'` exist.

I also tried

```
{'query': {
    'bool': {
        'must_not': [{
            'term': {
                'author': 'foo@bar.com'
            }
        }]
    }
}}
```

This returns a mix of documents where some have `'author': 'foo@bar.com'` and some don't.

Comment: you should try to add must_not at the same level of must. Like: bool > must, must_not. On the other hand, base level of should mean is "or". With this or, some unwanted docs can be appear.

Comment: You can try to create a really sentences about your search. For example, I want to get documents which are not user own docs and they are private. So, what is your should query? To complete our sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with Mapping changes in 5.0 (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_50_mapping_changes.html)

The following query worked as expected:

```
{'query': {
    'bool': {
        'must_not': [{
            'term': {
                'author.keyword': 'foo@bar.com'
            }
        }]
    }
}}
```